# Test an input using jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have this component:

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const Checkbox = () => {
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
    return (
        <div>
            <input onChange={()=> setChecked(!checked)} type="checkbox"/>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Checkbox;
```

Now, i want to check if i will click on input, the state is changing or not.
For this i made this:

```js
import React from "react";
import { shallow, configure, mount } from 'enzyme';
import Checkbox from "./Checkbox";
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'

configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

    it('should render checkbox', () => {
        const component = shallow(<Checkbox />);
        const btn = component.find('input');
        btn.simulate('click');
        ...
    });
```

Now, i can' figure out how to finish my test. Who can help?

Answer (score 1):

After clicking, you could check that the checkbox is now checked, using the following

```js
it('toggles checked state', () => {
    const component = shallow(<Checkbox />);
    const btn = component.find('input');
    btn.simulate('click');
    const checkbox = component.find({ type: 'checkbox' });
    expect(checkbox.props().checked).to.equal(true);
});
```

---

EDIT :
I'd like to give some more explanation, since my original answer works, but not as intended.

Your are defining a `checked` state, so I assume you'd like to make it the single source of truth for checking/unchecking the checkbox.
However, as is, the checkbox is currently **uncontrolled**. It means that it is checked/unchecked using the HTML API, and it's not related to the `checked` state you defined.
If you want this `checked` state to control the checkbox, you need to add the `checked` attribute to your input :

```
<input onChange={()=> setChecked(!checked)} type="checkbox" checked={checked} />
```

This way, the checkbox is controlled by your React component's state.

Ref : https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components